# Transposing using variables in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, transpose

How do i make this into wide transposed format?

```
  Id         Food   price      Date            
  1          K      200        2017-01-02
  2          L      150        2017-01-02
  3          M      110        2017-01-02
```

without using pivot and without hardcoding it?

I'm not able to figure out how to not hardcode this. Hardcoding would be:

```
select Date,
max(if(Food='K', 200, null)) as FoodA,
max(if(Food='L', 150, null)) as FoodB,
max(if(Food='M', 110, null)) as FoodC
from table
group by Date
```

Comment: You would need to write some dynamic SQL.

Comment: Either dynamic SQL in a stored proc or at application layer (Java, C#, Python, Perl, PHP, R, VB).